# Mean preservation for random uniform matrices

Tags: probability-theory

Is it true in general that for any random matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n,d}$ comprised of i.i.d. $\operatorname{Unif}(-1,1)$ entries, $$\operatorname{E}\left[\langle R\textbf{w}, R\textbf{x}\rangle\right] = \langle \textbf{w}, \textbf{x} \rangle$$ for any vectors $\textbf{w},\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$? If not, is there some way to modify the entries to achieve this?

Comment: What happens if $\mathbf w = \mathbf x$ are both equal to $(1,0,\ldots,0)$ ?

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand this counterexample correctly, $\operatorname{E}\left[\langle R\textbf{w}, R\textbf{x}\rangle\right] = \frac{1}{6}$, but $\langle \textbf{w}, \textbf{x} \rangle = 1$?

Comment: Hmm. I think that $\langle R\mathbf e_1, R\mathbf e_1\rangle$ is the $2$-norm of a vector of $n$ uniform random entries. The expectation of this should vary with $n$?

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Never mind, I think I've worked it out. $\operatorname{E}\left[\langle R\textbf{w}, R\textbf{x}\rangle\right] = 0$, but $\langle \textbf{w}, \textbf{x} \rangle = 1$.

Comment: Correction: $\operatorname{E}\left[\langle R\textbf{w}, R\textbf{x}\rangle\right] = \frac{n}{3}$, but $\langle \textbf{w}, \textbf{x} \rangle = 1$.